# Need explanation on Exception code

Tags: java, exception

I have some few doubts on exceptions.

Can anyone tell me why java doesnt allow us to create Checked Exception in a Subclass while it allows Unchecked exception in a subclass

Below exampple throws Compile time error when I use 'throws IOException' , BUT it doesnt throw any error when I use 'throws ArithmeticException' in a subclass.. I just wanna know the actual reason behind it, so can you please?

**Here is code (you will get compile time error)**

```
package com.exception.test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Parent {

    void msg()  {
        System.out.println("Parent...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.msg();
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {

    void msg() throws IOException   {
        System.out.println("Child...");
    }

}
```

**//using unCheckedException**

```
package com.exception.test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Parent {

    void msg()  {
        System.out.println("Parent...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.msg();
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {

    void msg() throws ArithmeticException   {
        System.out.println("Child...");
    }

}
```

Comment: There is rule for overriding method. In the subclass, at overridden method you can only throw exception declared in super class or exception which is type of super exception. For instance, if method methodA from super class declares IOException, overridden method from subclass can throw IOException or for example SocketException (subclass of IOException). There is always possible to declare and throw run-time exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a subclass method declares it can throw a checked exception that the parent doesn't, it breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which is one of the corner stones of object oriented programming.

Consider this bit of code, with `Child.msg` declared to throw a checked exception:

```
void doMsg(Parent p) {
    p.msg();
}
```

The program semantics break if you pass in a child object because the checked exception is now neither being caught nor thrown: the exception is no longer "checked."

Since unchecked exceptions can be thrown everywhere, declaring to throw one serves no other purpose than documentation. Therefore it can be allowed safely.

Comment: if u do not mind, can u explain me with some simple example.. why exactly java made such rule?

Comment: Are you asking "why does java follow the Liskov substitution principle?" or "why does declaring to throw checked exceptions in a subclass break it?"

Answer (score 0):

The `msg()` method in your parent class can throw any unchecked exception it likes. Hence, if you explicitly declare that your child throws an unchecked exception, you're not actually altering the contract. Your child method *may* throw an `ArithmeticException`, but so might your parent method.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have hit yet another pitfall of Java's misfeature known as Checked Exceptions. The error you are receiving is an actual problem that all Java professionals face: you are implementing a method with some code that happens to throw a checked exception not declared by the superclass method. The declared checked exceptions are a part of the Java method signature; you can reduce the list in a subclass, but you cannot expand it.

If this is more that just a "why" question, and you need a workaround, the standard idiom is

```
try {
   ...code that throws the checked exception...
} catch (TheCheckedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
```

This is called *exception wrapping*. If you have more than one or two undeclared checked exceptions, you can also use the opposite idiom, ensuring that all declared exceptions propagate transparently and all undeclared ones get wrapped:

```
try { 
   ...code that throws various checked exceptions...
}
catch (DeclaredEx1 | DeclaredEx2 | RuntimeException e) { throw e;} 
catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked exception can be narrowed down while overriding, but not can't be broaden. Unchecked exception need not be caught by the overridden methods

[From the java specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/exceptions.html)

> The checked exception classes named in the throws clause are part of
>   the contract between the implementor and user of the method or
>   constructor. The throws clause of an overriding method may not specify
>   that this method will result in throwing any checked exception which
>   the overridden method is not permitted, by its throws clause, to
>   throw.